# CLR never translated an alreday interpreted code again

Tags: .net, clr

Reading some book and author mentioned that the biggest difference between CLR and interpreter is that CLR never translate the same IL segment twice. it will reuse it in subsequent calls.

I wonder if CLR will keep this IL translation even after the program exits? if CLR just keeps the translation within the application's run, I would say some optimized interpreter will do same thing as well.

Comment: JITted code will not survive a restart of the process. You need to use ngen to do that. .net uses ngen on the standard assemblies to improve startup time.

Comment: An interpreter will never translate to machine code, since at that point it becomes a just-in-time compiler, just like the CLR. I believe the JVM uses a mix of interpretation and JIT compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IL will only be used once, it happens when the Just-in-time compiler translates it to machine code, just before the method starts executing.  That generated code is thrown away again when the AppDomain is unloaded.  Which normally happens when the program exits.

Keeping the generated code so it never has to be translated again is quite possible as well, that's the job of [ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).